# Capitalize first letter in string if first character is not letter?

Tags: python, string

I'd like to capitalize the first letter in a string. The string will be a hash (and therefore mostly numbers), so `string.title()` won't work, because a string like `85033ba6c` would be changed to `85033Ba6C`, not `85033Ba6c`, because the number seperates words, confusing `title()`. I'd like to capitalize the first letter of a string, no matter how far into the string the letter is. Is there a function for this?

Comment: What code did you try?

Comment: if you change a letter in a hash, it changes its meaning, rendering it virtually useless.

Comment: @njzk2 I'm not using it to check the validity of anything, just to create meaningless data out of meaningful data

Comment: Did anyone read the post before marking as duplicate ?

Comment: @njzk2 If you capitalize a letter in a hash encoded as hexadecimal digits, as is very, very, very, very, very common, the meaning doesn't change.

Comment: @BlaXpirit -- That's true :)

Comment: Did anyone read the post before reopening?

Comment: @BlaXpirit: the problem is, the answers there are not particularly helpful.

Comment: @thg435 ...How so? The accepted one solved the problem.

Comment: @millimoose: "solved the problem" is not enough for StackOverflow. It must be clean, smart, concise, robust and helpful for everyone else. Just like the Ashwini's one below.

Comment: @thg435 Those are subjective qualities that you could split hairs over ad nauseam to the point of making the flagging meaningless.

Comment: @millimoose:  Let's not question the obvious: the answer here is far better than there. So it was a good thing that we reopened and answered the question.

Comment: @thg435 _every_ answer here is better than there

Comment: @thg435 Thing is, I don't see the "far better". It's more robust (it handles the one known edge case), at the cost of being less straightforward, also doesn't handle Unicode input (which is not relevant for the stated use case but still) and the whole thing is a wash and hopefully you see what I mean by hair splitting now. (And I also consider robustness a "nice to have", not a requirement for SO answers.)

Comment: @tkbx: thanks ;) Although I'd rather delete mine as it's basically a dupe of Ashwini's.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `re.sub` with `count`:

```
>>> strs = '85033ba6c'
>>> re.sub(r'[A-Za-z]',lambda m:m.group(0).upper(),strs,1)
'85033Ba6c'
```

Comment: yeah, I forgot about `count`. Very neat!

Answer (score 6):

It is assumed in this answer that there is at least one character in the string where `isalpha` will return `True` (otherwise, this raises `StopIteration`)

```
i,letter = next(x for x in enumerate(myhash) if x[1].isalpha())
new_string = ''.join((myhash[:i],letter.upper(),myhash[i+1:]))
```

Here, I pick out the character (and index) of the first alpha character in the string.  I turn that character into an uppercase character and I join the rest of the string with it.